# what is the general and particular solution of : $\dfrac {dy}{dx}=7\sqrt {x}$ for $y(0)=1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

what is the general and particular solution of : $\dfrac {dy}{dx}=7\sqrt {x}$ for $y(0)=1$

I didn't get any idea whether to differentiate $7\sqrt {x}$ or not??

Comment: You need to integrate, not differentiate.

Comment: You are meant to integrate $7\sqrt{x}$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus we have $y(x) = y(0) + \int_0^x 7\sqrt{x'}{\rm d}x'$.

Comment: Albert, you've been around this site long enough to know better than post a question in which you show no effort, no work...etc.  Any way:  $y=\int 7(x)^{1/2}\,dx$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: write $$dy=7\sqrt{x}dx$$ and integrate